# How is "L" macro(?) defined?

Tags: c, winapi

```
static TCHAR szWindowClass[] = L"foo";
```

`L` is "glued" to the string `"foo"`. How come? A function or a macro as I am used to is something like `L("foo");`

Can anyone explain me how come L be glued to the string?

Comment: This is compiler feature/syntax.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`L` is not a macro, it's just the standard prefix for wide (`wchar_t`, "Unicode") string literals; the concept is similar to the `L` suffix for `long int` literals, `f` suffix for `float` literals and so on<sup>1</sup>.

By the way, if you are using `TCHAR`s you shouldn't be using `L` directly; instead, you should use the `_T()` or `TEXT()` macro, that adds `L` at the beginning of the literal if the application is compiled "for Unicode" (i.e. `TCHAR` is defined as `WCHAR`), or adds nothing if the compilation target is "ANSI" (`TCHAR` defined as `CHAR`).

---

1. Although in my opinion this is confusing - why suffixes for arithmetic types and a prefix for wide string literals?

Comment: What should I use along L, instead of TCHAR?

Comment: @Fabricio: [From the horse's mouth:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381407%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) `wchar_t`, or rather, `WCHAR` (to avoid confusion with Unix `wchar_t`, which is a 32bit type). Note the comments under that article, and the comments under my answer.

Comment: @Matteo: *Is* there such a thing as a `WCHAR_T` typedef, or is that a case-typo?

Comment: @DevSolar: sorry, I meant `WCHAR`, the WinAPI typedef.

Comment: "why suffixes for arithmetic types and a prefix for wide string literals" A: To simplify tokenization and make it fast.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: it really shows that three years ago I never did serious parsing, in hindsight it was obvious =) however, in this specific case I don't think it would really change much, IIRC the grammar for wide and narrow strings is the same, the only real advantage of knowing from start what kind of string is may be to encode it to wchar_t while reading instead of waiting till the end of the string to know if it needs additional processing (and how must it be flagged in the AST).

Answer (score 4):

It's not a macro, it's a token that the compiler recognizes as a prefix that has some special meaning.

The same happens with e.g. `l` as a suffix that produces `long` literals, as in `long x = 42l;`.

Comment: This answer is the only one that says "the compiler recognizes" explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a macro, just like `42ul` isn't a macro: It tells the compiler that "foo" is a **wide** string.

On a sidenote, it is not that well-defined what exactly a "wide string" actually *is*, so it's not portable. Unless you *have* to use TCHAR / `L"foo"` for API reasons, you are probably better off using C++11 Unicode support (if C++11 support is available to you): `u8"foo"` (UTF-8) or `U"foo"` (UTF-32), plus the appropriate string / array types.

Personal advice: Don't use UTF-16. Most people don't really understand it, as evidenced by that very argument over "wide" strings. ;-)

Comment: On the other hand, if you are working with the WinAPIs it's customary to use UTF-16 "wide strings" to play well with the rest of the platform.

Comment: That's exactly my point: WinAPI isn't UTF-16, they just say they are. (UTF-16 is a multibyte encoding, not a wide encoding.) Once you leave the BMP, things get "funny" with WinAPI. ;-) Reworded a bit to make it clearer.

Comment: Yes, it's a sad state of affairs; it started as UCS-2 when there wasn't anything besides the BMP and got converted "somehow" in UTF-16 around Windows 2000, which is probably the worst of all encodings. On the other hand, the "official" interface is (should be) UTF-16 (the `-A` versions are wrappers), and several new APIs exist only in the `W` version, so there's not much choice, even if you keep everything UTF-8 or UTF-32 internally when you have to call the OS APIs you have to go to UTF-16. ... and if some APIs are broken outside the BMP there isn't much we can do... :P

Comment: That's why I re-worded my answer a bit re "having to use TCHAR for API reasons". I work with various Unicode encodings on a daily basis, and it's sad to see how many *programmers* get UTF-16 / UCS-2 wrong...

Comment: @MatteoItalia and posterity: The problem is the [terrible imprecision of Microsoft when talking about these matters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381407%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). (Unicode is not a character encoding, UTF-16 characters are not "wide", and neither is Windows' `wchar_t`.) It's a terrible, terrible minefield, and if you *can*, you better avoid it altogether. `TCHAR`, incidentally, is probably the worst of it all, as it can be this *or* that depending on compiler settings...

Comment: Just to avoid misunderstandings, by "avoiding altogether" I was, of course, referring to the "clearly multibyte" UTF-8 and the "clearly wide" UTF-32 as options - not, by any chance, to the "clearly inadequate" ASCII / ISO encodings. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar - so should i use u8 along WCHAR? `WCHAR s = u8"foo";` EDit: but it says `'u8' undeclared (first use in this function)`

Comment: @Fabricio: No. What I meant to say is, if you can get away with it, don't touch the Windows API (WCHAR, TCHAR, etc.) *at all*, and use what the C++11 standard provides. However, 1) when on Windows, chances are you *cannot* get away with it; and 2) You don't know enough about Unicode yet. ;-) (That would be `char8_t s = `u8"foo"`...)

Comment: @DevSolar:  In modern versions of Windows, WinAPI is absolutely UTF-16.  Surrogate pairs work just fine.  It's true that when Windows first started to migrate to "wide" characters, it was pretty much limited to UCS-2 and the BMP, but that was a long, long time ago.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: With the state of MS documentation, it's hard to tell the difference. But good to know that it *should* be good to use.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

`#ifdef _UNICODE`

`#define L(str) L##str`

`#else`

`#define L(str) str`

`#endif`

Answer (score 0):

Improve it based on @Doo Hyeok Kim

```
#define DIAG "diag"
// innerally macro
#define __W(quote_string) L ## quote_string
// robust macro
#define _W(quoted_string_or_defined_string) __W(quoted_string_or_defined_string)
//std::wcout << _W(DIAG) << ", " << _W("_W(\"diag2\")") << ", " << __W("__W(\"diag3\")") <<std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to this question but this bugged me years ago.  Here is a link to some documentation giving the definition of L plus some others.

[cppreference.com string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)

```
L " (unescaped_character|escaped_character)* " (2)
2) Wide string literal. The type of a L"..." string literal is const wchar_t[].
```

Also a wikipedia article on [new string literals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#New_string_literals)